# Xamarin iOS - Code based on Provisioning Profile

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to make a code changed based on the provisioning profile used during the build?

For example, if I want my application deployed using ad-hoc and also App Store. I might want the ad-hoc build given to internal employees, which would show the login form for Active Directory. Then I may want the login form for the App Store version to show a different login option, such as OAuth.

I had considered something similar to when you want to run code in debug mode

`#IF Debug`

However, I cannot find any information on it or see any alternative way. It is quite a niche requirement, but because the app would be identical in every other way, I would rather not maintain two versions and the client doesn't want to show multiple login options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really answered your own question.  You can setup compiler symbols on a per-config basis (under project settings, Compiler).  So for you ad-hoc config, define a symbol AD_LOGIN, and for your app store config, define a symbol OA_LOGIN.  Then in your code

```
#if AD_LOGIN
// do AD
#if OA_LOGIN
// do OAuth
```

Comment: It seemed logical that it would be possible with compiler symbols like that but I couldn't see where to define them and I was a bit unsure if it would work.  I see it now under Properties -> Build in VS2017, I will give it a go tomorrow.